# PowerShell force [int] to wrap (IP to Long conversion)

Tags: powershell, ip, int

Just a quick question as I'm kind of new to math in PowerShell

I need to make a converter in PowerShell that converts IP to Long. It works fine for lower values, but on higher ones it is causing an Integer Overflow.

```
[int]$a = Read-Host "First bit of IP address"
[int]$b = Read-Host "2nd bit of IP address"
[int]$c = Read-Host "3rd bit of IP address"
[int]$d = Read-Host "4th bit of IP address"

$a *= 16777216
$b *= 65536
$c *= 256
$base10IP = $a + $b + $c + $d
Write-Host $base10IP
```

Works fine if I input some low-int IP address, like 10.10.10.10 (out 168430090)

But there are cases where this leads to Int overflow. I would like PowerShell to wrap around if [int] reaches maximum value and provide me a negative value.

I work as a service desk and one of the software I support needs IP in Long form, including negative values.

Is it doable in PowerShell ?

Please advise if you need more details or something is not clear.

Alex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple solution would be to use [long] instead of [int].

```
[long]$a = Read-Host "First bit of IP address"
[long]$b = Read-Host "2nd bit of IP address"
[long]$c = Read-Host "3rd bit of IP address"
[long]$d = Read-Host "4th bit of IP address"

$a *= 16777216
$b *= 65536
$c *= 256
$base10IP = $a + $b + $c + $d
Write-Host $base10IP
```

And you can do what you want in even less lines of code

```
[IPAddress]$ip = Read-Host "IP address"
$ip.Address
```

**UPDATE**

Your comment explains a long wasn't what you where after. It sounds like an int you are looking for.

I could not find a way to have PowerShell do unchecked (losing precision) conversions or arithmetic, but using the BitConverter class you can get it working.

```
[byte]$a = 10
[byte]$b = 113
[byte]$c = 8
[byte]$d = 203  
[BitConverter]::ToInt32(($a, $b, $c, $d), 0)
```

or

```
[IPAddress]$ip = "10.113.8.203"
$bytes = [BitConverter]::GetBytes($ip.Address)
[BitConverter]::ToInt32($bytes, 0)
```

Please note that IPAddress also supports IPv6 addresses, but this last conversion to an int clearly can't hold an IPv6 address.

Comment: Thanks. I need more coffee, should've thought of it before posting the question. Nontheless, it seems that the conversion I thought will work, will not do at all. The program I need to use accepts value -888639222 for IP 10.113.8.203. It seems that the value is some sort of other conversion I need to figure out before scripting it. (that value, when turned to HEX and read from right-left provides values for IP and I guess thats how it works, but its still some way for me to make up the algorithm.). Marked as answer and closed, I'll be back soon I guess :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update, I'll remember it. 
It turned out in the end, that the target software I had to use these values on, gives me back the Hash of IPAddress. I was able to get precisely what I looked for using 
    [IPAddress]$a = "192.168.0.1"
    $a.GetHashCode()
And the "GetHashCode()" method seems to transfer every byte to HEX value 10.113.8.203 in reversed order -> CB(203) 08(8) 71(113) 0A (10). And then, it fills the rest of value with FF FF FF FF (to get a 16-length HEX). And then in transfers the final value to Decimals. (FFFFFFFFCB08710A gives -888639222). Lession learned :-)

Comment: Both my answers in the update also produce -888639222 for 10.113.8.203.