# Powershell convert IP address to Integer

Tags: python, powershell, integer, ip

I want to use powershell to convert an IP address into an integer.

When I use python, it works well like this:

```
from netaddr import IPAddress
value1Numeric = int(IPAddress('10.36.5.0'))
print 'value1Numeric: '+str(value1Numeric)
```

That outputs a value of 170132736 which I'm expecting.

However, when I follow [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932443/powershell-force-int-to-wrap-ip-to-long-conversion) to do the same thing in powershell, I see this:

```
$IP = [IPAddress]"10.36.5.0".Trim()
$ip.Address
```

I get a value from powershell of 336906.

How do I get powershell to give me the same value as python did?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to change the byte order.

```
[IPAddress]$ip = "255.255.255.255"
$bytes = $ip.GetAddressBytes()
if ([BitConverter]::IsLittleEndian) {
        [Array]::Reverse($bytes)
}
[BitConverter]::ToUInt32($bytes, 0)
```

Comment: Isn't tcp in big endian byte order, even in windows?

Comment: @js2010: While `.GetAddressBytes()` indeed invariably returns the bytes in _network order_, i.e. in BIG-endian format, `[BitConverter]::ToUInt32()` uses the _host platform's_ endianness, hence the need to conditionally reverse the bytes.