# (Powershell) Sort IP Address Array

Tags: arrays, powershell, sorting

I need to sort an array of IP addresses and output the sorted array to include "," between each IP Address

```
$ip = "192.168.0.10, 192.168.0.12, 192.168.0.11, 192.168.0.9"
$ip =$ip.ToString()
$a = $ip.Split(",")
$new = for ($i=0;$i -lt $a.count;$i+=1) {$a[$i]}
$new | sort
```

This outputs the following (note that the 4th IP octet is not sorted properly):

```
192.168.0.11
192.168.0.12
192.168.0.9
192.168.0.10
```

Expected (Sorted) Output with "," delimiter:

"192.168.0.9"," 192.168.0.10"," 192.168.0.11"," 192.168.0.12"

Thank you for your help!

Here is the most elegant solution, IMO - thanks to Theo and Santiago Squarzon:

```
$ip = "192.168.0.10, 192.168.0.12, 192.168.0.11, 192.168.0.9"
$sortedip = ([IpAddress[]]($ip -split ',').Trim() | Sort-Object Address).IPAddressToString -join '","'
```

Output:

```
Write-Host `"$sortedip`"
"192.168.0.9","192.168.0.10","192.168.0.11","192.168.0.12"
```

Comment: You can use the examples here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72407929/powershell-sort-ip-addresses-in-txt-file/72408792 to sort ip addresses, then after sorted you can use `-join ', '`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon those examples appear to be relevant for IP ranges (subnet ranges) vs. array's that contain individual IP addresses.  I did try some of the code there to no avail.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - I get ```192.168.0.9```, ```192.168.0.12```, ```192.168.0.11```, ```192.168.0.10``` from that snippet - the "dot nine" address is in the wrong place because it's sorting lexically, not numerically...

Comment: @mclayton I see, yeah you're right, at least I can speak for [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72412034/15339544) which I know for sure it works: https://i.imgur.com/UlOefbN.png

Comment: @mclayton `'192.168.0.11', '192.168.0.12', '192.168.0.9', '192.168.0.10' | Sort-Object { [System.ValueTuple[int, int, int, int]]::new.Invoke($_.Split('.')) }` provides numeric sorting, that was my bad

Answer (score 2):

IP Addresses sort the same way as Versions. Casting the items in the sort works fine:

```
$ip = "192.168.0.10, 192.168.0.12, 192.168.0.11, 192.168.0.9"
$ip =$ip.ToString()
$a = $ip.Split(",")
$new = for ($i=0;$i -lt $a.count;$i+=1) {$a[$i]}
$new | sort {[Version]$_}
```

As a side note, the .ToString() and the for loop are unnecessary.  The following is identical in result.

```
$ip = "192.168.0.10, 192.168.0.12, 192.168.0.11, 192.168.0.9"
$new = $ip.Split(",")
$new | sort {[Version]$_}
```

Comment: Nice use of the ```Version``` class :-). You might want to ```Trim()``` the result of ```Split()``` though just to clean the data up a bit... ```$new = $ip.Split(",").Trim()```

Answer (score 1):

You've got two things going on:

#### Leading spaces

When you split your string you also need to trim it - the values you're actually sorting are:

```
192.168.0.10
 192.168.0.12
 192.168.0.11
 192.168.0.9
```

Note the leading space on items 2-4. The   (space) character is sorted *before* the `1` character, so `192.160.0.10` ends up at the bottom of the list and the sort results are:

```
 192.168.0.11
 192.168.0.12
 192.168.0.9
192.168.0.10
```

You can fix this by `Trim()`ing your values to remove any leading or trailing spaces:

```
$a = $ip.Split(",").Trim()
```

(This uses [Member-Access Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration?view=powershell-7.3) to trim all of the values in the split results, and creates a new array with the results of the `Trim()`, so now our output is:

```
192.168.0.10
192.168.0.11
192.168.0.12
192.168.0.9
```

That looks a bit better, but it's still wrong for a different reason...

#### Lexical sorting

Your sort is doing a *lexical* (dictionary) sort, not a semantic sort of ip address octets.

As all your addresses have the same first 3 octets, if we just sort the last octet we get this:

```
"10, 12, 11, 9".Split(",").Trim() | sort
10
11
12
9
```

Basically, `9` sorts *after* `1` so `9` appears after `10`, `11` and `12`.

For a slightly more convoluted example see this:

```
"1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22, 100, 200".Split(",").Trim() | sort
1
10
100
11
12
2
20
200
21
22
3
```

Everything is sorted by the first character in the string, and *then* by the second, and *then* by the third, rather than by their numerical value.

#### Answer

To get a semantic sort based on the numeric value of octets rather than the literal characters in the strings you need to *parse* the string into a form that sorts how you want it to.

Fortunately, you can convert an ip address string into an `[int]` that sorts according to the octet values - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36560061/3156906

You can also sort on a calculated value based on your input array - putting these two together gives:

```
$ip = "192.168.0.10, 192.168.0.12, 192.168.0.11, 192.168.0.9";

$ip.Split(",").Trim() | sort-object {
    # from https://stackoverflow.com/a/36560061/3156906
    $bytes = [System.Net.IPAddress]::Parse($_).GetAddressBytes();
    if( [BitConverter]::IsLittleEndian )
    {
        [Array]::Reverse($bytes);
    }
    [BitConverter]::ToUInt32($bytes, 0);
}

192.168.0.9
192.168.0.10
192.168.0.11
192.168.0.12
```

which also works with some other gotchas like:

```
$ip = "192.168.0.100, 192.168.0.12, 99.99.99.99, 192.168.0.9"

$ip.Split(",").Trim() | sort-object {
   ...
}

# 99.99.99.99
# 192.168.0.9
# 192.168.0.12
# 192.168.0.100
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a one-liner using the IP Address type accelerator:

```
([IpAddress[]]("192.168.0.10, 192.168.0.12, 192.168.0.11, 192.168.0.9" -split ',').Trim() | Sort-Object Address).IPAddressToString
```

Output:

```
192.168.0.9
192.168.0.10
192.168.0.11
192.168.0.12
```

If you want the result to become a comma delimited string, just append `-join ','` to the above code line

Comment: This only works for this specific example, IPAddress class does not implement IComparable and because of that, does not have a sorting definition. Try: `([IpAddress[]]('192.168.0.10, 192.168.0.12, 192.168.200.11, 192.168.0.9' -split ',').Trim() | Sort-Object Address).IPAddressToString`

Comment: This is perfect, @SantiagoSquarzon - thank you!

Comment: Also - Big Thank You to @Theo - much appreciated!